# Springboot JWT and OncePerRequest

Tags: spring-boot, security, jwt

here my code for the filter OncePerRequestFilter

```
try {
            String jwtToken = null;
            String username = null;

            jwtToken = jwtService.extractJwtFromCookie(request);

            if (jwtToken == null) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }

            username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwtToken);

            if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                if (jwtService.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                            null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
            response.getWriter().write(ex.getMessage());

            HelperJwt.setCookie(response, "jwt", "", 0);
            
        }
```

here is my filterChain

```
return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/welcome", "/auth/addNewUser", "/auth/generateToken", "/auth/refresh",
                                "/auth/deleteCookie")
                        .permitAll().requestMatchers("/auth/user/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/admin/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler()))
                .build();
```

my problem is :
i mange ExpiredJwtException in the filter. When i want to reach this url /auth/welcome not problem.
But when i want to reach this url /auth/user/ without token i have an error 403. But i want to intercept this error in order to customize and display the message for the user. We are ok that url marked by permitall are filtred by onceperrequestfilter
How do i do?

Thank for you help

I have only a message in the console with tag Debug.
If you want to inform the user of the reason for the failure with a message like "Token must be generated,"